# Arrange the sprites and text on the screen with Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, alignment, screen

I'm in the process of building my splash screen and I'm having some doubts related to align the elements and fit them right. How can make my sprites, text and other elements to occupy the right place and make them align on the screen, if you know what I mean. Should I use Table for that? How can I do that and how can I use the Table for this operation?

---

**I changed my code**: now may Player class extends the Actor class. 
But I'm getting some troubles because I added the player into the table but the player image appears almost in the middle of the screen. It wasn't happening before I have inserted the method align the table to the center, but I removed this method and the player still keeps with that position on the screen

A part from the SplashScreen in the show() method:

```
// Create the SpriteBatch
this.game.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

// Create the stage
this.game.stage = new Stage(this.game.viewPort);

// Create the table
this.table = new Table();
this.table.setFillParent(true);
this.game.stage.addActor(this.table);

// Insert the elements into the table
this.table.row();
this.table.add(this.game.player);
```

Now from the render() method from the SplashScreen:

```
// Set the projection matrix for the SpriteBatch
this.game.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.game.orthoCamera.combined);

// SpriteBatch begins
this.game.spriteBatch.begin();

// Display the ClimbUp logo
this.gameTitle.draw(this.game.spriteBatch);
this.table.draw(this.game.spriteBatch, 1);

this.game.player.draw(this.game.spriteBatch, 1);

// SpriteBatch ends
this.game.spriteBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when it comes to alignment in LibGdx Table is the way to go. Using Table's is very easy. 
There first thing you need to have is a Skin instance which takes a TextureAtlas parameter, then you can instantiate the Table.

```
Table someTable = new Table(); //Takes a Skin object as a parameter. 
someTable.add(); // Element as parameter.
someTable.row(); // Add a row if you need it.
someTable.add(); //Element as parameter.
someTable.debug(); // Don't forget to call debug();
```

When you have the Table object instantiated and ready to go just add it to a Stage object and let it do the drawing and other stuff.

```
someStage.addActor(someTable);
```

But before doing any of this you should probably take a look [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table).

Comment: Yes I saw that before asking here, but it didn't explain me how do I can put a sprite in my table or even a text. That's my question. I also tried to find on youtube but didn't find anything that explains that to me

Comment: You cannot directly add a Sprite, however you can add a Scene2DUI object called Actor. For text you can simply call the .add() method which takes a String as an argument (There are also other overloaded methods that allow you pass a font and string as the arguments).